# How do you translate this: Ich messe meiner Zeit Wert zu

Tags: phrase

I have difficulties to understand this phrase:

> Ich messe meiner Zeit Wert zu

How would you translate it?

Answer (score 4):

I'd translate
`Ich messe meiner Zeit Wert zu`
with
`I consider my time valuable`

Comment: I wonder if this would be used as anything other than an icy putdown? A "polite" way of saying, "Buzz off and stop wasting my time."

Comment: @EugeneSeidel, most likely. I could think about a terminally ill person saying the same, with a context of take advantage of the remaining time ...

Comment: Do not forget that, despite the existence of the internet, there are still people today, for whom boredom is an issue.

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, it depends on the context the sentence is used/in what tone the sentence is uttered. Most likely, I would translate your sentence as follows:

> - I give/assign value to my time.
> - For me, time is money.
> - Time is precious.